# How to obtain the top most visible item in a ListView using Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, listview, compact-framework

How can I obtain the index of the top visible item in a C# `ListView` using the .NET Compact Framework version 3.5? The Compact Framework does not have the `TopItem` property in the `ListView` class.

My goal is to retrieve the index, refresh my `ListView` that contains data from a database, and return to that item after the refresh is completed. I can us the `EnsureVisible(int index)` method to automatically scroll, but I need the index first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no explanation as to why there isn't a CF property for this, since the underlying Win32 control supports it.  You must call `SendMessage` with the `LVM_GETTOPINDEX` constant.  Something along these lines:

```
private const int LVM_GETTOPINDEX = 0x1027;

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public static int GetTopIndex(this ListView lv)
{
    return SendMessage(lv.Handle, LVM_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0);
}
```